# How to center my current position? (Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to center my current location in Google Maps. This will center a location with a specific latitude- and longitude-variable.

```
var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(62.39081100, 17.30692700);
```

But I tried to grab the users location with this function:

```
function grabMyPosition() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(centerMe);
    } else {
        alert("You don't support this");
    }
}
function centerMe(center) {
    var me_location = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lon: position.coords.longitude
    };
}
```

And then do this:

```
var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(me_location.lat, me_location.lon);
```

But then I get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
```

That's because I'm storing and filling this "me_location" variable inside a function. How can I make it "global" so it could be used outside my function?

Comment: `me_location` is not accessible from outside `CenterMe` function..

Comment: I thought so, but how "bypass" this problem?

Comment: You return the object at the end of the function, and call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(centerMe());` instead.

Comment: Why don't you work async?
`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` receive a callback function as argument.. so center the map inside callback..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function grabMyPosition() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(centerMe);
    } else {
        alert("You don't support this");
    }
}
function centerMe(position) {
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude
    );

    map.setCenter(coords);
    // or
    map.panTo(coords);
}
```

Supposing your `map` variable is global..

Answer (score 2):

you are not returning any value from the function centerMe